# Azure - Obtain user refresh token fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm sitting whole day on it and maybe i need to refresh my eyes, but I'm unable to get the user refresh token using [Azure OAuth2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) guide.

I will explain my scenario:

1. I have client page using react I call the `/authorize` API to obtain the `code` for the following scopes: `"email", "openid", "offline_access", "profile"`. A consent window is being opened and I agree to the terms.
   (I might not need all of them but during my session i got errors and decided to go to large scale permissions only to get it working)
2. The `code` is being sent to my server where I call the `/token` API with the same scopes I stated in the client when I called `/authorize` and the same redirect URI.

The base URL is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` for the calls above

Now I get BAD_REQUEST with the following reason:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application 
with ID <CLIENT_ID> named <APP_NAME>. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: <ID1>\r\nCorrelation ID: <ID2>\r\nTimestamp: 2020-10-02 19:48:18Z",
  "error_codes": [
    65001
  ],
  "timestamp": "2020-10-02 19:48:18Z",
  "trace_id": <ID1>,
  "correlation_id": <ID2>,
  "suberror": "consent_required"
}
```

At the App Registration I gave permission to the app on the above scopes and all of them from the same group of API:
[image: App registration permissions]

When I go to my Microsoft Account to view the application I can see the permissions below which seems like I'm missing the email at least:
[image]

I read several posts on the matter, important to say that I'm trying to login from a different microsoft account, I went to the admin page on that account and set enabled users to consent for the permissions stated above but still no use.
[image]

Per request adding code snippets of the flow:

1. I have a React application - using library [`react-ms-login`](https://github.com/nishch/react-ms-login) where it is using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` API to obtain the authorization code, it opens the consent window and once closes it sends it to my server.
   The component can be seen as below:

   `<ReactLoginMS  clientId={MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID} redirectUri="https://localhost:3000/msComplete"  scopes={["email", "openid", "offline_access", "profile"]} responseType="code"   handleLogin={(data) => login(data)} />`
2. Flask Application gets the authorization code and do the following:

   ```
   def get_refresh_token(code):
   headers = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
   data = {
       'client_id': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
       'scope': ["email", "openid", "offline_access", "profile"],
       'code': code,
       'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:3000/msComplete',
       'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
       'client_secret': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET
   }
   response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', headers=headers, data=data)
   response.raise_for_status() # getting 400 with the mentioned error
   return response.json()
   ```

Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?
Would love for any kind of help because this is the 4th time I'm deleting the App registration and starting over :)
Thanks

Comment: What URL are you using for the /token call?

Comment: Forgot to mention it,`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`. i will add it to the post too, thanks

Comment: Can you share the code for how you're making the authorization request and the token request?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Yes, Added to the main post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the error message is not super clear, your issue is how you are building the token request body.

If you pass an array as one of the values in the data of a POST request:

```py
data = { 'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
requests.post('https://example.com', data=data)
```

The **requests** library [will encode it](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) as follows:

```
foo=a&foo=b&foo=c
```

So, in your code where you include an array of strings as the `scope` value for the token request:

```py
'scope': ["email", "openid", "offline_access", "profile"],
```

You are causing the resulting request to have multiple individual `scope` parameters in the body:

```
...&scope=email&scope=openid&scope=offline_access&scope=profile&...
```

Instead, what you want is a single `scope` parameter with each scope value separated by a space:

```py
'scope': 'openid email offline_access profile',
```

Which will be encoded as:

```
...&scope=openid%20email%20offline_access%20profile&...
```

Here's the corrected code for building the token request body:

```py
data = {
    'client_id': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': "email openid offline_access profile",
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:3000/msComplete',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_secret': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET
}
```

Comment: gosh i knew it is something silly. yea it works thanks